# Google GCM server domain gcm-http.googleapis.com will be existing after April 11?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Now we use FCM client API and the connection server uses GCM for push service. May I post a request to the gcm-http.googleapis.com/ domain after April 11th? 
Will not I be able to connect after that? or the GCM server will redirect to FCM server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update-server-endpoints), you'll have to update your server endpoints.

> Update your server code to use new FCM endpoints for sending messages
>   via HTTP and XMPP. Note that the new FCM version of
>   `gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/` is `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/` (without
>   "http").

Though FCM supports HTTP and XMPP protocols that are virtually identical to the GCM server protocols, so you don't need to update your sending logic for the migration.

Comment: Thanks, I knew then guide line. 
I wonder if the gcm domain service is shutting down.